# Meromorphic functions being continuous functions in the one point compactification of $C$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, meromorphic-functions, riemann-sphere

[image]

This is an exercise in Conway that I am stuck at. In fact I am surprised at this result. I cannot find a way to deal with the infinite points of $f$. Could anyone help me how to solve this exercise?

Comment: Is $G$ an arbitrary punctured domain in the complex plane?

Answer (score 1):

If $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of complex numbers which converges to $z_0$ and if $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=\infty$ (this is a property of the poles). Therefore, $\tilde f$ is continuous at $z_0$. Since $\tilde f$ is also continuous at the non-poles of $f$, it is continuous everywhere.